# Computer auto-reboot. Running Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1

I run Windows 8.1 because someone told me it's fast. However, after I changed my os from Windows 7 to 8.1, I cannot shut down the machine with only one hit on the shut down option. It always boots up again all by itself. Is this a hardware problem or system one? I've never come across this case when it's running win 7. I often shut down the computer by ctrl alt delete BTW.

Comment: I have seen this on some Windows 7 SP1 computers.  I have never been able to determine why it happens.  Every time I have seen it, it has been on someone's Toshiba computer, which made me stop recommending that anyone buy that brand.

Comment: Does this solve your problem: [Shutting down the computer- reboots instead](http://superuser.com/questions/733846/shutting-down-the-computer-reboots-instead)?

Comment: The hardware has wakes like "Wake on Lan" "wake on time" , you could check those in your UEFI Or BIOS. Also check that power on after ac off is set to stay off, in case the PSU is acting funny. It can also be caused with buggy drivers and software because it did not reach shutdown , it crashed, and you still have it set to auto-restart on a crash (default).  in that case it only looks like that is what it is doing, but a trace, or looking in the event viewer might show what really happened.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I asked a friend of mine and he told me to set all things to default in BIOS though I didn't know clear about what I was doing. It doesn't work perfectly but it worked a little because the PC might not boot up again for several times.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the applications running on the system from USB drives and ethernet connections also cause such issues. Hence run the following command on your sytem

"powercfg.exe /lastwake"

This will list the events causing the reboot, then manually closing the specified events will help you to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a try. Will let you know if it works. BTW, merry christmas!